Storybook + Vite no loader is configured for .node files
Edit:
I have updated my storybook config to this:
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-vite";

import { nxViteTsPaths } from "@nx/vite/plugins/nx-tsconfig-paths.plugin";
import { mergeConfig } from "vite";
import { UserConfig } from "vite";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../../../../packages/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  core: {
    builder: "@storybook/builder-vite"
  },
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-vite",
    options: {
      builder: {
        viteConfigPath: "../../../vite.config.ts"
      }
    }
  },
  refs: {
    next: {
      title: "Next.js",
      url: "http://localhost:7007"
    }
  },
  viteFinal: async (config: UserConfig) =>
    mergeConfig(config, {
      plugins: [nxViteTsPaths()],
      optimizeDeps: {
        exclude: ["etech-ui-utils", "universal-fs", "@mapbox", "@ngrok/ngrok"],
        include: ["bcrypt", "dotenv", "express"]
      },
      build: {
        rollupOptions: {
          input: "../../../../packages/**/**"
        }
      }
    })
};

export default config;

// To customize your Vite configuration you can use the viteFinal field.
// Check https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/vite#configuration
// and https://nx.dev/recipes/storybook/custom-builder-configs


As well as adding vite-plugin-commmonjs.
Now I am getting a new error:

Here is my root package.json:
{
  "name": "@etech-ui/source",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "lint:check": "pnpx eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "pnpx eslint . --fix",
    "format:check": "pnpx prettier . --check",
    "format:fix": "pnpx prettier . --write",
    "language-lint": "pnpm alex",
    "test": "pnpx vitest",
    "storybook:dev": "pnpx nx run next:storybook --port 7009 && pnpx nx run vite-react:storybook --port 7008 --config-dir",
    "storybook:build": "pnpx nx run next:build-storybook & pnpx nx run vite-react:build-storybook",
    "build": "pnpx rollup -c && node build/buildTsx.js && node build/buildJsx.js",
    "docs:dev": "cd apps/docs && pnpm dev",
    "docs:build": "cd apps/docs && pnpm build",
    "prepare": "pnpx husky && husky install",
    "commitlint": "commitlint --edit"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx,astro,mjs,cjs,spec.ts,spec.tsx}": "pnpx eslint --cache --fix",
    "*.{js,css,md,ts,tsx,astro,mjs,cjs}": "pnpx prettier --write",
    "*.{md,mdx}": "pnpm run language-lint",
    "*.js": "eslint --cache --fix",
    "*.{js,css,md}": "prettier --write"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^19.3.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^19.2.2",
    "@eslint/js": "^9.7.0",
    "@nx/js": "19.5.7",
    "@nx/rollup": "19.4.1",
    "@nx/storybook": "19.4.1",
    "@nx/vite": "19.5.7",
    "@nx/web": "19.5.7",
    "@nx/workspace": "19.4.1",
    "@storybook/cli": "^8.2.8",
    "@swc-node/register": "~1.9.2",
    "@swc/cli": "~0.3.14",
    "@swc/core": "~1.5.29",
    "@swc/helpers": "~0.5.12",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/eslint__js": "^8.42.3",
    "@types/node": "18.16.9",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.7.0",
    "alex": "^11.0.1",
    "core-js": "^3.36.1",
    "eslint": "^9.7.0",
    "happy-dom": "^14.12.3",
    "husky": "^9.1.1",
    "nx": "19.4.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.39",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "rollup": "^4.20.0",
    "rollup-plugin-esbuild": "^6.1.1",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.36.0",
    "swc-loader": "0.1.15",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.9",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.3",
    "typescript": "~5.4.5",
    "typescript-eslint": "^7.16.1",
    "verdaccio": "^5.31.1",
    "vite": "^5.3.4",
    "vite-plugin-commonjs": "^0.10.1",
    "vitest": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "nx": {
    "includedScripts": []
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@changesets/cli": "^2.27.7",
    "@ngrok/ngrok": "^1.4.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.4",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "ngrok": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "tailwind-variants": "^0.2.1"
  }
}


SB package.json:
{
  "name": "storybook",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^8.2.8",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^8.2.8",
    "@storybook/core-server": "^8.2.8",
    "@storybook/react": "^8.2.8",
    "@storybook/react-vite": "^8.2.8",
    "@storybook/test": "^8.2.8",
    "nock": "13.5.4",
    "mock-aws-s3": "4.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "2.1672.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}


Original Post:
I'm trying to setup Storybook 8.2 with Vite. Here is my storybook config:
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-vite";

import { nxViteTsPaths } from "@nx/vite/plugins/nx-tsconfig-paths.plugin";
import { mergeConfig } from "vite";
import { UserConfig } from "vite";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../../../../packages/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-vite",
    options: {
      builder: {
        viteConfigPath: "../../../vite.config.ts"
      }
    }
  },
  refs: {
    next: {
      title: "Next.js",
      url: "http://localhost:7007"
    }
  },
  viteFinal: async (config: UserConfig) =>
    mergeConfig(config, {
      plugins: [nxViteTsPaths()],
      build: {
        rollupOptions: {
          external: [
            "universal-fs",
            "packages/etech-ui-utils/**",
            "@ngrok/ngrok-darwin-arm64",
            "@ngrok/ngrok-darwin-universal"
          ]
        }
      }
    })
};

export default config;

// To customize your Vite configuration you can use the viteFinal field.
// Check https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/vite#configuration
// and https://nx.dev/recipes/storybook/custom-builder-configs


However, when running npx storybook dev I get an error:
✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@ngrok+ngrok-darwin-arm64@1.4.0/node_modules/@ngrok/ngrok-darwin-arm64/ngrok.darwin-arm64.node

    ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@ngrok+ngrok@1.4.0/node_modules/@ngrok/ngrok/index.js:141:36:
      141 │             nativeBinding = require('@ngrok/ngrok-darwin-arm64')
          ╵                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@ngrok+ngrok-darwin-universal@1.4.0/node_modules/@ngrok/ngrok-darwin-universal/ngrok.darwin-universal.node

    ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@ngrok+ngrok@1.4.0/node_modules/@ngrok/ngrok/index.js:116:32:
      116 │         nativeBinding = require('@ngrok/ngrok-darwin-universal')
          ╵                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/storybook@8.2.8_@babel+preset-env@7.25.3_@babel+core@7.25.2_/node_modules/storybook/bin/index.cjs:23
  throw error;
  ^

Error: Build failed with 3 errors:
../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js:86:21: ERROR: No loader is configured for ".html" files: ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.11/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@ngrok+ngrok@1.4.0/node_modules/@ngrok/ngrok/index.js:116:32: ERROR: No loader is configured for ".node" files: ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@ngrok+ngrok-darwin-universal@1.4.0/node_modules/@ngrok/ngrok-darwin-universal/ngrok.darwin-universal.node
../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@ngrok+ngrok@1.4.0/node_modules/@ngrok/ngrok/index.js:141:36: ERROR: No loader is configured for ".node" files: ../../../node_modules/.pnpm/@ngrok+ngrok-darwin-arm64@1.4.0/node_modules/@ngrok/ngrok-darwin-arm64/ngrok.darwin-arm64.node
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.21.5/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1472:15)
    at /Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.21.5/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:945:25
    at /Users/ekrich/git/etech-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.21.5/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1353:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errors: [Getter/Setter],
  warnings: [Getter/Setter]
}

Node.js v22.5.1

It's worth noting that I'm in an NX monorepo this storybook is nested in apps/storybook/vite-react. There are other dependencies that are problematic so I'm trying to ignore them with rollup options. However, I still get the error.
I have tried several Github suggestions without luck. Essentialy I want Vite to only watch where stories are found. How can I do that?
